# v-for not displaying content

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am having an issue with `v-for` inside my component..

**code:**

```
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <h1 slot="header">
      {{modalData.title}}
    </h1>
    <p slot="body">
      {{modalData.assignee}} <!-- works -->
      <div v-for="a in modalData.assignee"> 
        <p>Testing v-for iterate</p> <!-- does not display -->
      </div>
    </p>
  </modal>
```

The value of `modalData.assignee` is

```
[ { "id": 4, "username": "testUser" } ]
```

This is exactly what displays where `{{modalData.assignee}}` is, however I do not see the message `Testing v-for iterate`.

`modalData.title` also displays correctly.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

I noticed that directly assigning the username also fixes the problem.

```
this.$root.$on('modalEvent', function(event) {
  this.showModal = true;
  this.modalData = event;
  this.modalData.assignee = this.modalData.assignee[0].username //works
}),
```

Comment: Anything in your console?

Comment: No, no errors or anything that would suggest something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be due to invalid markup.

A `<p>` tag should not have other block-level children. Change

```
<p slot="body">
```

to

```
<div slot="body">
```

or any other valid element and it all works fine.

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/efa0u103/